# Insert throwing "column name is specified more than once in SET Clause" only one one table

Tags: sql-server, node.js, insert

I'm using node+mssql to bulk insert data. I had a test table made that I cloned from the production table on the same server. On the test table everything is working fine, insert happens without a hitch.

When I change the target to the production table I get: `The column name 'CallStartTime' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause.` I've logged all the column's I'm inserting and all of the data the code and data is exactly the same. This leads me to believe that there is a configuration difference between the tables. There are no triggers on either table, what else may cause this?

I can provide code snippets but I'm not sure that's going to help I'm pretty certain my code isn't the issue.

The insert statement is formed inside mssql here are the parameters I pass:

```
    table.columns.add('From', mssql.VarChar(50), {nullable: true, primary: false});
    table.columns.add('To', mssql.VarChar(50), {nullable: false, primary: true});
    table.columns.add('CallStartTime', mssql.DateTime, {nullable: false, primary:true});
    table.columns.add('CallDirection', mssql.VarChar(5), {nullable: true, primary: false});
    table.columns.add('User', mssql.VarChar(150), {nullable: true, primary: false});
    table.columns.add('QueueName', mssql.VarChar(50), {nullable: true, primary: false});
    table.columns.add('DialedNumber', mssql.VarChar(20), {nullable: true, primary: false});
    table.columns.add('CallDuration', mssql.Time, {nullable: true, primary: false});
    table.columns.add('CallResult', mssql.VarChar(50), {nullable: true, primary: false});
```

...

```
            table.rows.add(
                callLogs[i].from,
                callLogs[i].to,
                callLogs[i].startTime,
                callLogs[i].direction,
                callLogs[i].User, 
                callLogs[i].QueueName, 
                callLogs[i].dialedNumber, 
                callLogs[i].duration, 
                callLogs[i].result
            );
```

Comment: Please post `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I added to the original. mssql takes care of formatting the insert but I have posted the parameters I pass to it.

Comment: Please intercept query that is sent to SQL Server.

Comment: The problem is in some part of the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: @TabAlleman how is it in the code if the exact code writes fine to table A but not to table B.

Comment: Have you checked the sql server side to see if a trigger or other code executed on insert is causing the problem?

Comment: @PeterVC so I did check trigger there are non set up. I did try to move the same data from the Test table to the Production table and that actually went off without a hitch.

I'm now attempting to capture the query sent to the SQL server. I'm not at all a server person though so I'm learning as I go I'll be back here once I capture it.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda so I managed to capture the sql this morning and its depicting the issue clearly. I narrowed it down to somewhere in the msnodesqlv8 module where suddenly its wanting to pass a second 'CallStartTime':

`insert into TABLE ( [From], [To], [CallStartTime], [CallStartTime], [CallDirection], [User], [QueueName], [DialedNumber], [CallDuration], [CallResult]) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into this issue. I managed to solve it. mssql/msnodesqlv8 when building the table in table.js lib runs a query on the provided connection to pull the table parameters. It uses these parameters to build the statement. Here is the query that it runs to grab those parameters:

```
WITH t_fuzzy_cte(id, full_name, table_name) AS

(SELECT  TOP (1)
        0 AS id,
        TABLE_CATALOG + '..' + TABLE_NAME AS full_name,
        TABLE_NAME
        FROM
                your_DB_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'your_table_name%')
,
t_exact_cte(id, full_name, table_name) AS
(SELECT TOP (1)
                0 AS id,
                TABLE_CATALOG + '..' + TABLE_NAME AS full_name,
                TABLE_NAME
      FROM
                        your_DB_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
),
t_name_cte(full_name, table_name) AS
(
        SELECT
            ISNULL(e.full_name, f.full_name) AS full_name,
            ISNULL(e.table_name, f.table_name) AS table_name
    FROM t_fuzzy_cte AS f
                LEFT OUTER JOIN t_exact_cte AS e ON e.id = f.id
)
SELECT
        sc.table_catalog,
        sc.table_schema,
        sc.table_name,
  c.name name,
  t.Name type,
  c.max_length,
  c.precision,
  c.scale,
  c.is_nullable,
  c.is_computed,
  c.is_identity,
  c.object_id,
  (
  CASE
  WHEN CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (SELECT NAME
                           FROM FN_STAGE_TEST.sys.objects
                           WHERE TYPE = 'PK')
    THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) AS is_primary_key,
  (CASE
  WHEN CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (SELECT NAME
                           FROM your_DB_name.sys.objects
                           WHERE TYPE = 'F')
    THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) AS is_foreign_key
FROM your_DB_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES st
  INNER JOIN your_DB_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sc
    ON sc.TABLE_CATALOG = st.TABLE_CATALOG
       AND sc.TABLE_SCHEMA = st.TABLE_SCHEMA
       AND sc.TABLE_NAME = st.TABLE_NAME
  LEFT JOIN your_DB_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE u
    ON sc.TABLE_CATALOG = u.TABLE_CATALOG
       AND sc.TABLE_SCHEMA = u.TABLE_SCHEMA
       AND sc.TABLE_NAME = u.TABLE_NAME
       AND sc.COLUMN_NAME = u.COLUMN_NAME
  cross join t_name_cte r
  INNER JOIN
  your_DB_name.sys.columns c ON c.name = sc.column_name
  INNER JOIN
  your_DB_name.sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
  INNER JOIN
  your_DB_name.sys.tables ta ON ta.name = r.table_name
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  your_DB_name.sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  your_DB_name.sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
  c.object_id = ta.object_id
  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND sc.TABLE_NAME = r.table_name
  AND (sc.TABLE_SCHEMA = '' or '' = '')
  AND (ta.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('') or '' = '')
```

An index on the production table specifically indexing the CallStartTime column was causing this query to return the row twice. To fix the issue I had to remove the index.